# On Change not firing when input value is entered

Tags: javascript, onchange

I cannot figure out why my input is not showing the results of my calc. based on the input change. I have checked to see if there is an output in the console.log and there is, I am use an IDE environment to develop an have noticed errors when coding that don't involve the code it is the IDE I'm wondering if this is the case? Or is there something not right with the code on my part.

Any help would be appreciated

HTML

```
<td>InPut</td>
<td>
  <input class="" id="bhp_1" type="number" value="440">
</td>

<td>OutPut</td>
<td>
  <input class="" id="bpm_l60" type="number" value="567.11">
</td>
```

JavaScript

```
var  manualEntry = function(){
  var bhp = parseFloat($('#bhp_1').val());
  var bhp2 = parseFloat($('#bhp_2').val());
  var bhp3 = parseFloat($('#bhp_3').val());
  var bhp4 = parseFloat($('#bhp_4').val());
  var bhp5 = parseFloat($('#bhp_5').val());
  var bhp6 = parseFloat($('#bhp_6').val());
  var bhp7 = parseFloat($('#bhp_7').val());
  var bhp8 = parseFloat($('#bhp_8').val());
  var bhp9 = parseFloat($('#bhp_9').val());
  var bhp10 = parseFloat($('#bhp_10').val());
  var bhp11 = parseFloat($('#bhp_last').val()); 
  return {
     val: bhp,
     val2: bhp2,
     val3: bhp3,
     val4: bhp4,
     val5: bhp5,
     val6: bhp6,
     val7: bhp7,
     val8: bhp8,
     val9: bhp9,
     val10: bhp10,
     val11: bhp11
  }
}
manualEntry();

// console.log(manualEntry());

//Filter for return object 
var bhpKeys = Object.keys(manualEntry())
var bhpmatchingKeys = bhpKeys.filter(function(key) {
  return key.indexOf('val', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6','val7','val8','val9','val10','val11') !== -1
});
var bhpmatchingValues = bhpmatchingKeys.map(function(key) {
  return manualEntry()[key]
});


var bpm_l60 = function() {
  var mySpline = new MonotonicCubicSpline(
    [4000, 8000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 60000, 80000, 100000], bhpmatchingValues);
  var total = mySpline.interpolate(43592.990983668795);
  $('#bpm_l60').val(+total.toFixed(2));
  $('#bpm').val(+total.toFixed(2));
  return total;
};
bpm_l60();
```

Onchange listener

```
document.getElementById("bhp_1").onchange = (function() {
    manualEntry();
    bpm_l60();
});
```

Here is a Code pen example of the problem I'm having.
http://codepen.io/coryk/pen/zqgPyz?editors=1011

Answer (score 0):

Put your js code inside

```
window.onload = function() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling the `onchange` listener? If it's before the `<input>` elements are created, it won't work. You're already using jQuery, try

```
$(document).on("change", "#bhp_1", function () {
    manualEntry();
    bpm_l60();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your onchange event to the following:

```
document.getElementById("bhp_1").onchange = function() {
    manualEntry();
    bpm_l60();
}
```

What you are currently doing is wrapping your function in an additional method call `()` which is not the correct syntax to use for binding an onchange event to an element.